# Error when apostrophe is put on status

Tags: php

I'm making something now that involves users putting statuses, but whenever a user puts a status with an apostrophe or double quotes, they get errors.

Can anyone help? Thanks!
p.s "Your post does not have much context to explain the code sections; please explain your scenario more clearly."

my get-posts.php

```
<?php

require('database/connect.php');

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY date DESC");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

$email = $row['email'];

// To find username

$username = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");

$name = mysql_fetch_assoc($username);

// To make the date look prettier

$id = $row['id'];

$date_get = mysql_query("SELECT date FROM posts WHERE id='$id'");

$time = mysql_fetch_assoc($date_get);

$mysqldate = $time['date'];

$phpdate = strtotime( $mysqldate );

$DayMonthDay = date('l, F j', $phpdate);

$HourMinutePMAM = date('g:ia', $phpdate);

$date = $DayMonthDay." at ".$HourMinutePMAM;

echo "<div class='home-echoed-posts'>";

echo "<a href='#' class='home-echoed-posts-name'>".$name['name']."</a> ";

echo "<div class='home-echoed-posts-post'>".nl2br(stripslashes($row['post']))."</div>";

echo "<div class='home-echoed-posts-date'>".$date."</div>";

echo "</div>";

} 



?>
```

and post.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
require('database/connect.php');

if(empty($_POST['post'])){
    header('Location: home.php');
    }

$post = $_POST['post'];

$useremail =  $_SESSION['email'];

$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO posts (post, email) VALUE ('$post', '$useremail')");

if($result==1) {
    header('Location: home.php');
    }else{
    die('We have experienced some technical problems, please try again');
    }
?>
```

Comment: What errors? Please elaborate?

Comment: Ask them not to put singe or double quotes

Comment: There is the code, but still no error message. How are we supposed to guess it?

Comment: ^^ Because, error is one I put in myself, its in the first code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to escape the input from the user?

in PHP there is `addslashes ($user_status)`

The reference is:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

If you are using DBMS, be sure to use DBMS specific escape before saving the status into the database:

- mysql_real_escape_string() for MySQL
- pg_escape_string() for PostgreSQL

Comment: OP is using the `mysql_` implementation, so you may update the post with [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php). +1

Comment: thanks Fabricio. I've updated the function on my post. =)

Comment: Where would that go?
Noob here =/

Comment: Hi, you can do $post = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['post']); on post.php

Comment: Thank you so much, you're a real helper!